# excel regex end of line

Tags: regex, vba, excel, replace

I am looking for a regex for excel 2007 that can replace all instances of **-3** ONLY at the end of the string, replacing it with absolutely nothing (removing it). There are instances of -3 throughout the strings, however I need to remove only the ones at the end. This is being integrated into a macro, so find and replace using a single regex is preferred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this without `Regex` by using VBA's `Instr` function. Here is the code:

```
Sub ReplaceIt()

Dim myRng As Range
myRange = Range("A1") ' change as needed

If InStr(Len(myRange.Text) - 2, myRange.Text, "-3") > 0 Then

    myRange.Value = Left(myRange, Len(myRange) - 2)

End If


End Sub
```

**Update**

Based on Juri's comment below, changing the If statement to this will also work, and it's a bit cleaner.

```
If Right (MyRange, 2) = "-3" Then MyRange=Left(MyRange, Len(MyRange)-2)
```

Comment: a quick glance at this - some of the strings may have -3 somewhere other than at the end, would this still work? I will try this out once I get in the office here in a few!

Comment: @Scott I have first thought of this routine. But according to the OP's description he could have multiples of `-3` at any location of the String. :) In your case perhaps OP needs to loop over your methods till all last `-3` are gone. e.g. `-3thisstring-3has many-3-3-3-3`

Comment: @NRGdallas - yes, this will only eliminate only the `-3` at the end of the string. But as @bonCodigo points out, if there are multiple `-3`s at the end it will only remove the first. Not sure if that will be an issue or not.  I mainly provided this solution as its "all-in" VBA solution, with no need to reference other objects.

Comment: `If Right (MyRange, 2) = "-3" Then MyRange=Left(MyRange, Len(MyRange)-2)`

Comment: @JüriRuut -. Duh! Thanks for the code enhancement. It's funny how sometimes when the mind thinks of a solution first, it misses the easier, softer way! I am editing my post now.

Comment: getting an error:

Run-time error'13': Type Mismatch

edited the line slightly to the following:
If InStr(Len(myRange) - 2, myRange, "-3") > 0 Then

Comment: ended up taking the basic formula behind this and simply applying it to another column, copy pasting special, then deleting the column - ill probably go back and revisit this section once the entire thing is working and optimize it, for now moving forward. Thanks for putting me in the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following:-

Edit as per OP's comments:

```
Sub mymacro()
Dim myString as String
 //'--do stuff
 //'-- you could just do this or save the returning 
 //'-- string to another string for further processing :)
 MsgBox replaceAllNeg3s(myString)
End Sub

Function replaceAllNeg3s(ByRef urstring As String) As String
Dim regex As Object
Dim strtxt As String

  strtxt = urstring
  Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")

  With regex
    //'-- replace all -3s at the end of the String
    .Pattern = "[(-3)]+$"
    .Global = True
    If .test(strtxt) Then
      //'-- ContainsAMatch = Left(strText,Len(strText)-2)
      //'-- infact you can use replace
      replaceAllNeg3s = Trim(.Replace(strText,""))
    Else
      replaceAllNeg3s = strText
    End If
  End With

End Function

//'-- tested for 
//'-- e.g. thistr25ing is -3-3-3-3
//'-- e.g. 25this-3stringis25someting-3-3
//'-- e.g. this-3-3-3stringis25something-5
//'-- e.g. -3this-3-3-3stringis25something-3
```

Comment: Please try this out and comment. As you mentioned this `regex` will only remove one last `-3` at the end of the string. So you need to remove many of then at the end of the string please do comment.

Comment: I will try this out as soon as I get into the office - I have a macro that is about 200 steps so far, would I just copy and paste the entirety of this into the macro where this step would need to be using the code editor?

Comment: @NRGdallas I have updated to show what you need to do :) Looking forward to your comments.

Comment: @NRGdallas let us know how it went and if you need further clarification or help on the same.

Answer (score 1):

Unless its part of a bigger macro, there's no need for VBA here! Simply use this formula and you'll get the result:

```
=IF(RIGHT(A1,2)="-3",LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-2),A1)
```

(assuming that your text is in cell `A1`)